# millis(), equivalent function in 8051?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, timer, 8051

I am making a project with 8051 which require a millis() function as like arduino, please suggest me how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the clock speed, you can tell the µC to do some idle task. One instruction will take \$ \frac{1}{F_{clk}} \$ to process. You can then write a assembly code (to have a maximum accuracy) to make the µC count his own clock \$ \frac{T_{ms}}{F_{clk} * 1000} \$ time. You can find some more detail on [this website](http://www.circuitstoday.com/software-delay-routine-in-8051)